# find out dimension of object in image in cpp

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I have a image which contains object. I have to find out the dimensions of the object (in pixels). Does anyone know how I could calculate that using cpp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution    This is the code..

```
Mat src = imread("C:/ball.jpg");
    if (src.empty())
        return -1;

    Mat hsv;
    cvtColor(src, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);

    Mat bw;
    inRange(hsv, Scalar(19, 204, 153), Scalar(27, 255, 255), bw);

    vector<vector<Point> > contours;

    findContours(bw.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
     Mat dst = Mat::zeros(src.size(), src.type());
      Mat coordinates = Mat::zeros(src.size(), src.type());
    drawContours(dst, contours, -1, Scalar::all(255), CV_FILLED);

    dst &= src;
    imshow("src", src);
    imshow("dst", dst);


     for(unsigned int i=0;i<contours.size();i++)
   {
     cout << "# of contour points: " << contours[i].size() << endl ;

     for(unsigned int j=0;j<contours.size();j++)
     {
         cout << "Point(x,y)=" << contours[i][j] << endl;
     }

     cout << " Area: " << contourArea(contours[i]) << endl;
}
     imshow("coordinates",coordinates);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

I am a search engine. Using me, you can locate all sorts of useful information, like [API references manuals](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/refman.html) and even [sample code](http://linuxconfig.org/display-image-attributes-with-opencv).

Have a nice day!

Comment: No, maybe the question wasn't clear but he asked about a region inside the image. Contours is the answer.

Comment: Actually, she (not he) explained what she really wanted inside a comment, instead of editing her question. I answered the original question, not the comment.

Comment: Oh. Sorry about that. I don't know Indian names so well.